# File is not saved in database as .zip

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, zip

My upload form allows people to only upload .zip and .rar files. I want to make sure that whenever a user uploads his/her file, it will be inserted in the database as a zip file.

What I have done so far is change the type to varbinary in the database. I also insert the files with the `$fileName` variable.

My code:

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "myserver";
$ftp_user_name = "myuser";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
// get de bestand extensie
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
$destination_folder = "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/FilesUpload";
$destination_file = $destination_folder . "/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// some code for the connection and only allowing .zip and .rar files.

if (!$upload) { 
    echo "Er is iets fout gegaan, excuses voor het ongemak";
} else {

    // insert data in de database
    global $wpdb;
     $number_of_rows_inserted = $wpdb->insert('wpex_programma', [
     'naam' => $fileName]);

      var_dump($number_of_rows_inserted);
```

This inserts the data in the database, it then shows the following:

[image]

As you can see, it is inserted as a .zip. However, when I click on it, it shows the following message:

[image]

It does not download it as a .zip file but as a .bin. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you click on what, exactly?  It looks like you're inserting the *name* of the file into the database.  Where are you saving the file itself?

Comment: When I click on the P7_03_uitwerking.zip in the database. When the user uploads the file, it is eventually saved in a remote ftp server and in the database (the latter one I am attempting now). You can see the path where all the files are saved in the ````$destination_folder```` variable. @David

Comment: *"the latter one I am attempting now"* - It looks like you're approaching that attempt backwards.  You're trying to download the file *from* the database before you've attempted to save the file *to* the database.  Right now you're just saving the *name* of the file.  Look at your call to `$wpdb->insert()`.  The only parameter you pass it is the file name.  Generally the approach is to store only a reference to the file in the DB, not the file itself.  To store the file itself you may need to Base64-encode it first.

Comment: You are not clicking on anything _“in the database”_, that phrasing doesn’t even make any sense. This is a functionality phpMyAdmin, a frontend for database administration, is providing for you. If you don’t like how it works - well then you will have to go and do some research whether it is configurable in some way, and if not, write your own functionality to provide such a download. (Or realize that _files_, under most normal circumstances, don’t really belong into a database to begin with …)

Comment: @David, well. I want that when the files in the db are retrieved (which they already are), the users will be able to download them. Is that possible when I only save a reference to the zip file? Like a path?

Comment: @JohanDelft: Yes, it's possible.  Usually the recommended approach is to save the file on the file system and save the path to the file in the database.  Then in your application you would use the database data to create links to the files.  Ideally these links would point to a PHP script and provide an identifier for the database record.  That script would use the identifier to fetch the record from the DB, and use the path in that record to stream the file to the user.  The DB record could also include things like the file name, MIME type, size, etc.